# Как рекурсивно(SQL) вывести parent и child?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, orm

Имеется следующая SQL-команда:

```
        WITH RECURSIVE menu AS (
            SELECT id, parent_id, name, CAST(name AS CHAR(500)) AS path
            FROM app_menu 
            WHERE name = %s

        UNION 

        SELECT app_menu.id, app_menu.parent_id, app_menu.name, menu.path || app_menu.name
        FROM app_menu
            JOIN menu 
                ON app_menu.parent_id = menu.id)   

        SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY path;'''
```

Здесь я вывожу в иерархическом порядке только детей объекта. Как мне вывести родителей тоже. У меня получается бесконечный цикл, если писать:

```
ON app_menu.parent_id = menu.id OR app_menu.id= menu.parent_id
```

Мне нужно уложиться в один запрос в SQL

Comment: Bo-первых, UNION ALL. Во-вторых, добавьте ещё один CTE, которое аналогично первому выберет всех родителей. Ну и во внешнем запросе UNION ALL результатов обоих CTE (само собой один из CTE нужно начать не с исходной записи, а с её родителя/потомка).

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за ответ. Но все же я не совсем понимаю, как это написать. Вы не могли бы помочь с этим?

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант набора пути из иерархии (parent-child):
Тестовый пример

```
create table app_menu(id int,parent_id int,name varchar(20));
insert into app_menu values
 (1,0,'Files')
  ,(2,1,'Open')
    ,(21,2,'Recent')
    ,(22,2,'Favorites')
       ,(23,22,'Excel files')
       ,(24,22,'Word files')
         ,(25,24,'Word templates')
  ,(3,1,'Print')
    ,(31,3,'Print HP')
    ,(32,3,'Print .PDF')
  ,(4,1,'Close');

WITH RECURSIVE menu AS (
  SELECT id
     , parent_id
     , name
     , CAST(name AS varCHAR(500)) AS path
     ,id as sId ,1 as lvl
  FROM app_menu 
  WHERE name ='Open' -- %s

UNION all

  SELECT case when app_menu.id=menu.parent_id then menu.Id 
         else app_menu.id end as id 
     ,case when app_menu.id=menu.parent_id then app_menu.parent_Id 
      else menu.parent_id 
      end as parent_id
     ,app_menu.name
     ,case when app_menu.id=menu.parent_id then
          cast(app_menu.name || '-' || menu.path as varchar(500))
      else
          cast(menu.path || '-' || app_menu.name as varchar(500))
      end path
     ,menu.sId ,menu.lvl+1 as lvl
  FROM app_menu
  JOIN menu 
      ON  ( app_menu.id = menu.parent_id)
       or (menu.parent_id=0 and  app_menu.parent_id = menu.id)
  where lvl<6 --это только для отладки
  )   

SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY path;
```

Результат запроса на тестовых данных

| id | parent_id | name | path | sId | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | Files | Files-Open | 2 | 2 |
| 22 | 0 | Favorites | Files-Open-Favorites | 2 | 3 |
| 23 | 0 | Excel files | Files-Open-Favorites-Excel files | 2 | 4 |
| 24 | 0 | Word files | Files-Open-Favorites-Word files | 2 | 4 |
| 25 | 0 | Word templates | Files-Open-Favorites-Word files-Word templates | 2 | 5 |
| 21 | 0 | Recent | Files-Open-Recent | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | Open | Open | 2 | 1 |

Тот же запрос, если в качестве начального задать  пункт 'Favorites'

| id | parent_id | name | path | sId | lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 2 | Favorites | Favorites | 22 | 1 |
| 22 | 0 | Files | Files-Open-Favorites | 22 | 3 |
| 23 | 0 | Excel files | Files-Open-Favorites-Excel files | 22 | 4 |
| 24 | 0 | Word files | Files-Open-Favorites-Word files | 22 | 4 |
| 25 | 0 | Word templates | Files-Open-Favorites-Word files-Word templates | 22 | 5 |
| 22 | 1 | Open | Open-Favorites | 22 | 2 |

[Пример здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5b17a/3)
Выглядит несколько заморочено, но общая идея такая: В рекурсии присоединяем к пути слева и потом справа. При этом текущий элемент имеет Id самого правого из текущего пути, parent_id самого левого из текущего пути.
Было бы интересно посмотреть комментарий @Akina на данное решение и более подробное пояснение описанного им подхода к решению данной задачи.